# MySql : How do I have Horizontal Union of results?

Tags: mysql

I am looking to generate the results into the horizontal union. I could able to combine together and generate the results. However, I need to show the results in the expected results format.

**SQL**

```
(SELECT 
    kpa_id AS 'KPA', SUM(weightage) AS 'Total'
FROM
    pmm_question_details
WHERE
    weightage NOT LIKE '%-%'
GROUP BY kpa_id) UNION (SELECT 
    kpa_id AS 'KPA', SUM(weightage_value) AS 'Acheived'
FROM
    pmm_answer_details
WHERE
    application_id = 2
        AND archive_value = 'No'
GROUP BY kpa_id)
```

**Actual Results**

```
1   14
2   37
3   19
4   40
5   51
6   24
1   12
2   19
3   0
6   2
```

**Expected Results**

```
1   14  1 12
2   37  2 19
3   19  3 0
4   40  6 2
5   51
6   24
```

Comment: That's a displaying issue. Better do that in your program logic and not in SQL

Comment: What you're after looks `more like a join` than a `union`.  You could generate/simulate  a `row_number for each record and join on the row numbers.  However, this assumes you know which table has more records and want results in a particular order.  If you don't know which table is bigger, then you'd have to perform a left join tbl1 to tb2 and then a left join tbl2 to tbl1 an union the results. as mySQL doesn't support a full outer join.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If we can assume pmm_question_Details will always have as many or more records than pmm_answer_details... then two subqueries and a left join should do the trick with a join on a uservariable rownum (RN)

```
SELECT A.KPA, A.Total, B.KPA, B.Acheived
FROM (SELECT kpa_id AS 'KPA'
           , SUM(weightage) AS 'Total'
           , @RN1 := @RN1 + 1 as RN
      FROM pmm_question_details
      CROSS JOIN (SELECT @RN1 :=0) r1
      WHERE weightage NOT LIKE '%-%'
      ORDER BY KPA
      GROUP BY kpa_id) A

LEFT JOIN (SELECT kpa_id AS 'KPA'
                , SUM(weightage_value) AS 'Acheived'
                , @RN1 := @RN2 + 1 as RN
           FROM pmm_answer_details
           CROSS JOIN (SELECT @RN2 :=0) r2
           WHERE application_id = 2
             AND archive_value = 'No'
           ORDER BY KPA
           GROUP BY kpa_id) B
 on A.RN = B.RN
ORDER BY A.KPA
```

Though I must admit I don't see why a rownumber is needed if you could just left join on the KPA_ID in the first place...

if this could be the Expected results... (and again assuming pmm_question has all the IDs which could be in pmm_answer... )

```
Expected Results

1   14  1 12
2   37  2 19
3   19  3 0
4   40
5   51
6   24  6 2
```

Then the query would just be...

```
SELECT A.KPA, A.Total, B.KPA, B.Acheived
FROM (SELECT kpa_id AS 'KPA', SUM(weightage) AS 'Total'
      FROM pmm_question_details
      WHERE weightage NOT LIKE '%-%'
      GROUP BY kpa_id) A
LEFT JOIN (SELECT kpa_id AS 'KPA', SUM(weightage_value) AS 'Acheived'
           FROM pmm_answer_details
           WHERE application_id = 2
             AND archive_value = 'No'
           GROUP BY kpa_id) B
 on A.KPA = B.KPA
```